# How to change the position of material-ui's dialog?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using material-ui in my react app, is there a way I can change the position when the dialog is opened? now it's always centered.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can create styles and pass it through `classes` prop. Here is an example of how you could do that.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, Dialog } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  dialog: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 10,
    top: 50
  }
});


function Example() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Dialog
      classes={{
        paper: classes.dialog
      }}

      /* rest of the props */
    >
      {/* content of the dialog */}
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```

Comment: " classes={{
        paper: classes.dialog
      }}".what does the "paper" do here?

Comment: As you can see in an official documentation (https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/), it is the way to override the styles of the Paper component that's used inside the Dialog.

Comment: " dialog: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: "50%",
    top: "50%",
    transform: "translate(-75%,-50%)",
  }"
 Why doesn't the transform work here?

Comment: Not sure. Works for me. Maybe try with `transform: "translate(-75%,-50%) !important"`.

Comment: Cool, it's working after adding important. Really appreciate your answers!

Comment: position:'absolute' and important shoul not be used, they can break the normal behaviour of the component.
Please consider using flex properties to do the same thing

Answer (score 10):

I would say don't use `position: absolute`, it could break the scrolling behavior. The position was control differently with `scroll='paper'` or `scroll='body'`

You can use the following code to always align your dialog to the top of the page with two custom classes.

- Demo: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-dialog-position-4xwq2?file=/dialog.tsx)
- See the [original article with explanation](https://trungk18.com/experience/react-material-ui-dialog-position/)

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  topScrollPaper: {
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  },
  topPaperScrollBody: {
    verticalAlign: 'top',
  },
})

function SimpleDialog(props: SimpleDialogProps) {
  const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    <Dialog
      onClose={handleClose}
      aria-labelledby="simple-dialog-title"
      open={open}
      scroll="paper"
      classes={{
        scrollPaper: classes.topScrollPaper,
        paperScrollBody: classes.topPaperScrollBody,
      }}
    ></Dialog>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi ,  how about position to bottom , is like this ? alignItems: 'flex-end'   verticalAlign: 'bottom',  ????  or verticalAlign: 'top ' still .

Answer (score 8):

For MUI 5, we can use both SxProps and styled() utility:

Via SxProps:

```
import { SxProps } from "@mui/material";

// flex-start: to position it at the top
// flex-end: to position it at the bottom
// center: to position it at the center

const sx: SxProps = {
   "& .MuiDialog-container": {
     alignItems: "flex-start"
   }
};
<Dialog
    open={infoModalOpen}
    onClose={() => setInfoModalOpen(false)}
    sx={sx}
    scroll="paper"
>
  ....
</Dialog>
```

Via styled components:

```
import styled from "@mui/system/styled";

const StyledDialog = styled(Dialog)(({theme}) => ({
    "& .MuiDialog-container": {
      alignItems: "flex-start"
    }
}));

<StyledDialog
   open={infoModalOpen}
   onClose={() => setInfoModalOpen(false)}
   sx={sx}
   scroll="paper"
 >
  ....
</StyledDialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

@radovix's and @Sumit Wadhwa's answers are correct. In case you don't want to use `makeStyles`, Here is how I resolved it.

When `scroll="body"`;

```js
<Dialog
  fullWidth
  onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
  open={true}
  scroll="body"
  PaperProps={{ sx: { mt: "50px", verticalAlign: "top" } }}
>
  {/* Dialog Content here */}
</Dialog>;
```

When `scroll="paper"`;

```js
<Dialog
  fullWidth
  onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
  open={true}
  scroll="paper"
  sx={{
     "& .MuiDialog-container": {
        alignItems: "flex-start",
     },
  }}
  PaperProps={{ sx: { mt: "50px" } }}
>
  {/* Dialog Content here */}
</Dialog>;
```

You can adjust the `margin-top` however you like