# How to change Material-UI Dialog Html location

Tags: html, reactjs, user-interface

how do I change the location? Or is there no alternative ?

```
<div role="presentation" class="MuiDialog-root" style="position: fixed; z-index: 1300; inset: 0px;">
```

[image]

I want to put it in:

```
<div id="root" class="flex" aria-hidden="true">
```

I want the result :

```
<div id="root" class="flex" aria-hidden="true">
   <div role="presentation" class="MuiDialog-root" style="position: fixed; z- 
   index: 1300; inset: 0px;">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the styles and pass it through the classes prop, it's mentioned in the documentation here: https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/ and there is a example in this thread here on how to do it: [How to change the position of material-ui's dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61439557/how-to-change-the-position-of-material-uis-dialog)

Comment: Sorry, I mean, I want to put the entire HTML syntax in the specified place.

Comment: Sorry, my content is updated to make the needs more clear

Comment: According to the docs you have to pass the classes property in order to change the initial css added. You can see how the prop i passed here in an example taken and simplified from the docs: https://codesandbox.io/s/ex-tnzfz?file=/demo.js