# Material UI: Display the dialog at the bottom left of the page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a project to monitor employees and I have a sidebar in this project.

As is evident in the first two pictures, there is a sidebar, and inside it there is a button. Then I press the button, then the dialog appears in the "bottom left" of the page, and I want to do the same idea.

[image]

[image]

And the thing that I did is in the third picture,
I create a button within the sidebar, and when I click on this button, a dialog appears, but the dialog appears in the middle of the page and not at the bottom left of the page.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        dialogPaper: {
            maxWidth: '36rem',

            height: '33rem',
        },
        border: {
            borderBottom: '10rem'
        }, paper: {
            // padding: theme.spacing(2),
            // textAlign: 'center',
            // color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
        },
        dividerColor: {
            backgroundColor: '#000000',
        },
        resize: {
            fontSize: 24,
            color: '#BDBDBD'
        },
        oneEdgeShadow: {
            background: '#384047',
            boxShadow: '0 0 0 4px #384047, 0 4px 4px black',
        }
    })
);

export default function FormDialog() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    const navigation =  useNavigate();

    const onMySettings=() =>{
        console.log('Clicked on My settings');
        navigation('/dashboard/workspace-sidebar/settings');
    }

    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
                Open form dialog
            </Button>
            <Dialog classes={{paper: classes.dialogPaper}}  open={open} onClose={handleClose}
                    aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">

                <Grid container xs={12}>
                    <Grid item xs={2}>

                        <List component="nav" aria-label="main mailbox folders"
                              style={{paddingLeft: '1rem', fontSize: '14px', color: '#BDBDBD', 
                             lineHeight: 1}}>
                            <ListItem button style={{
                                fontWeight: 500,
                                fontSize: '11px',
                                lineHeight: 1,
                                whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                                overflow: 'hidden',
                                textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
                                color: '#BDBDBD'
                            }}>
                                <ListItemAvatar>
                                    <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg"/>
                                </ListItemAvatar>

                            </ListItem>
                        </List>

                    </Grid>
                    <Divider  classes={{root: classes.dividerColor}}  orientation="vertical" flexItem/>
                    <Grid item xs={5}>
                        <List component="nav" aria-label="main mailbox folders"
                              style={{paddingLeft: '1rem', fontSize: '10px', color: '#BDBDBD', 
                            lineHeight: 1}}>
                            <ListItem button style={{
                                paddingBottom: '1rem',
                                fontWeight: 500,
                                fontSize: '10px',
                                lineHeight: 1,
                                whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                                overflow: 'hidden',
                                textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
                                color: '#BDBDBD'
                            }}>
                                <ListItemAvatar>
                                    <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg"/>
                                </ListItemAvatar>
                                <ListItemText>Ali Baba {/*Workspaces*/}</ListItemText>
                            </ListItem>

                            <ListItem button>
                                <ListItemText primary="Settings"/>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItem button>
                                <ListItemText primary="Import/Export"/>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItem button>
                                <ListItemText primary="People"/>

                                <Button onClick={handleClose} startIcon={<PersonAddIcon />} style={{   
                                borderRadius: 2,background: '#7b68ee'}} variant="contained">
                                    Invite
                                </Button>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItem button>
                                <ListItemText primary="Spaces"/>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItem button>
                                <ListItemText primary="Integrations"/>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItem button>
                                <ListItemText primary="Template Center"/>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItem button>
                                <ListItemText primary="Trash"/>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItem button>
                                <ListItemText primary="Security & Permissions"/>
                            </ListItem>
                        </List>

                    </Grid>
                    <Divider classes={{root: classes.dividerColor}}  orientation="vertical" flexItem/>
                    <Grid item xs>
                        <List component="nav" aria-label="main mailbox folders"
                              style={{paddingLeft: '1rem', fontSize: '14px', color: '#BDBDBD', 
                             lineHeight: 1}}>
                            <ListItem button style={{paddingBottom: '1rem'}}>
                                <ListItemAvatar>
                                    <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg"/>
                                </ListItemAvatar>
                                <ListItemText>Ali Baba</ListItemText>
                            </ListItem>

                            <ListItem button onClick={onMySettings}>
                                <ListItemText primary="My Settings"/>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItem button>
                                <ListItemText primary="Notifications"/>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItem button>
                                <ListItemText primary="Layout size & style"/>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItem button>
                                <ListItemText primary="Rewards"/>
                            </ListItem>

                        </List>



                        <List component="nav" aria-label="main mailbox folders"
                              style={{paddingLeft: '1rem', fontSize: '14px', color: '#BDBDBD', 
                            lineHeight: 1}}>
                            <ListItem button>
                                <ListItemText primary="Log out"/>
                            </ListItem>

                            <Divider classes={{root: classes.dividerColor}} variant="middle" />
                            <ListItem button>
                                <ListItemText primary="Help"/>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItem button>
                                <ListItemText primary="Hotkeys"/>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItem button>
                                <ListItemText primary="Dark mode"/>
                            </ListItem>

                        </List>

                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
              
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61439557/how-to-change-the-position-of-material-uis-dialog#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the paper style of the `Dialog` component.

First create your desirable style and position by `makeStyles` as below:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  paper: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0
  }
});
```

and then pass it to the Dialog component:

```
<Dialog
  classes={{ paper: classes.paper }}
  onClose={handleClose}
  aria-labelledby="simple-dialog-title"
  open={open}
>
```

[working example in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-5q96f?file=/demo.js:1229-1373)

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to use makeStyles like in the suggested answers. Just use the PaperComponent prop of the Dialog and define your custom PaperComponent (which is the container of elements for the Dialog component).

That should do the trick:

```
<Dialog
  PaperComponent={(props) => {
    return <PaperComponent style={{position: "absolute", bottom:0, left: 0 }} {...props}/>
  }}
  onClose={handleClose}
  aria-labelledby="simple-dialog-title"
  open={open}
>
```

It has a preset margin to keep the paper element in a safe area to not get too close to the edges. You can disable it by setting `margin: 0` in the styles props of the `<Paper/>` component.