# Center material UI dialog in div (default centered by window)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dialog

I have a StyledDialog made by withStyles

```
const StyledDialog = withStyles({
  paper:{
    // top:100,
    padding: 0,
    boxShadow:'none',
    height: 188,
    // width:'35%',
    borderRadius:14
  }
})(Dialog);
```

By default, it is centered in window fullscreen.
But I want to make it centered by its container.
Is there any elegant way to do that?

Comment: Hello, can you give us an example of your code ?

Comment: Well it is just a three Grid items and in middle item is a container now.

Comment: Similar question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61439557/how-to-change-the-position-of-material-uis-dialog